# How can I track WebSockets in Node.js (ws) using Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using Node.js and `ws` for my WebSocket servers and want to know the best practice methods of tracking connections and incoming and outgoing messages with Azure Azure Application Insights.

It appears as though this service is really only designed for HTTP requests and responses so would I be fine if I tracked everything as an event? I'm currently passing the JSON.parse'd connection message values.

Comment: Hi, 'best practices' questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow because they are primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Updated the question so it's not a "best practice" question, but one where I'm asking how to do something in my particular case.

Comment: It still seems unclear what you're objectively asking -- "would I be fine if I" what do you mean by "fine"? Is there a specific problem you are seeking to avoid? Have you tried the implementation you're asking about yet?

Comment: Yes. Didn't seem like the right way to do it. I'm betting there's a better way that someone knows who has experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What to do here really depends on the semantics of your websocket operations. You will have to track these manually since the Application Insights SDK can't infer the semantics to map to Request/Dependency/Event/Trace the same way it can for HTTP. The method names in the API do indeed make this unclear for non-HTTP, but it becomes clearer if you map the methods to the telemetry schema generated and what those item types actually represent.

If you would consider a receiving a socket message to be semantically beginning an "operation" that would trigger dependencies in your code, you should use `trackRequest` to record this information. This will populate the information in the most useful way for you to take advantage of the UI in the Azure Portal (eg. response time analysis in the Performance blade or failure rate analysis in the Failures blade). Because this request isn't HTTP, you'll have to mend your data to fit the schema a bit. An example:

```
client.trackRequest({name:"WS Event (low cardinality name)", url:"WS Event (high cardinality name)", duration:309, resultCode:200, success:true});
```

In this example, use the `name` field to describe that items that share this name are related and should be grouped in the UI. Use the `url` field as information that more completely describes the operation (like GET parameters would in HTTP). For example, `name` might be "SendInstantMessage" and `url` might be "SendInstantMessage/user:Bob".

In the same way, if you consider sending a socket message to be request for information from your app, and has meaningful impact how your "operation" acts, you should use `trackDependency` to record this information. Much like above, doing this will populate the data in most useful way to take advantage of the Portal UI (Application Map in this case would then be able to show you % of failed Websocket calls)

If you find you're using websockets in a way that doesn't really fit into these, tracking as an event as you are now would be the correct use of the API.